# How to allow only two users to log into a domain computer?

Tags: windows, username

at work we have a training room which is used for training and meetings. A domain computer has been placed there for presentations etc.

A generic account has been set up on Active Directory to allow all users to log into the computer with this one account. 
However, all other domain accounts are still able to log in to this workstation.

What I would like to do is only allow two users to be able to log in. That is the training room user and administrator. How would this be done so that when the PC is powered on it automatically has the training room user selected - and all that needs to be done is the password?

Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/438693/gpo-how-to-limit-the-users-able-to-logon-to-pc) question has been answered before.  Adapt to your specific configuration as needed.

Comment: If you have the admin credentials, you can simple right click on "My Computer" > Manage > Users & Groups.  There you should be able to remove the group that allows anyone and only explicitly set the users you want.  (I can't confirm that menu path as I am not near a windows box and you didn't specify a version).